# Entering conference outputs in Pure (Elsevier)

Tags: conference, presentation, software, poster, abstract

Many universities (including my own) use [Pure](https://www.elsevier.com/products/pure) (an Elsevier product for institutional research information management) to report research outputs.

My question is about entering conference outputs in Pure.

In particular, suppose I submit an abstract to a conference and it is accepted for a poster or a presentation (not a paper in the proceedings).

When entering this in Pure there are 3 options in my university:

1. Contribution to a conference/Abstract
2. Contribution to a conference/Poster
3. Contribution to a conference/Presentation

My university presents no guidance on which I should use.

Given that the abstract had been accepted with a resulting poster or poster/presentation, which should I use:

Abstract or poster/presentation

Is there a difference? And under what circumstances should I choose each of these categories?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, it would be ***Contribution to a conference/Abstract***.
What you submitted was an abstract, and not a paper for presentation.

Given the scenario, all three are possibilities. I'll nonetheless go with *Contribution to a conference/Abstract* (provided the abstract is published as the conference output whether as program book or conf website).

However, if I were to go with Aalto's [guidance for ACRIS](https://www.aalto.fi/en/services/adding-articles-manually-to-acris), I might probably opt for poster if the end outcome is the poster, and presentation if it were presented. Likewise [TU/e Pure guidance](https://purefaq.tue.nl/pure/faq/index.php?action=artikel&cat=4&id=66&artlang=en) or [Groningen guide](https://www.rug.nl/library/support/pure/using-pure/add-content-to-pure/submission-guide-3.0/conference-contribution?lang=en).

Comment: My "intuition" is the opposite. Enter it as it was accepted, not as it was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you enter it after decisions have been made or that you have the chance to update an earlier entry, I think it should be entered (or updated) as it was accepted, not as it was submitted.

Other possibilities are misleading, even dishonest. If you submit a presentation and have a poster (only) accepted, then entering it as a presentation is false. The opposite case is true as well.

Your "contribution" is what was accepted.